# Django ajax-generated hidden field not in request.POST

Tags: ajax, django

I'm using https://drew.tenderapp.com/faqs/autosuggest-jquery-plugin/options-api to render an autocomplete field:

```
        <h1>Quick Tags</h1>
        <div class="fieldset">
            {{ vocabularies.vocabulary_1.errors }}
            <p>{{ vocabularies.vocabulary_1 }}</p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                ////http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin
                $("input#id_vocabulary_1").autoSuggest("/staff/taxonomy/ajax", {selectedItemProp: "name", selectedValuesProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name", startText: "Enter terms.", keyDelay: 50, minChars: 1, queryParam: "term", asHtmlID: "vocabulary_1", extraParams: "&app=taxonomy&model=TaxonomyData&vocabulary=1"});
            </script>
        </div>
```

Which renders a hidden field:

```
    <li class="as-original" id="as-original-vocabulary_1">
<input id="vocabulary_1" type="text" name="vocabulary_1" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off" class="as-input">
<input type="hidden" class="as-values" name="as_values_vocabulary_1" id="as-values-vocabulary_1" value="test,new term,">
</li>
```

However, the values from this field are not present in the POST dictionary. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? In particular, the part that is making the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem; if the div that contains the form opening tag is closed, all fields after that are not contained in the POST dictionary.